# Target Properties changes by xcodebuild command

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, command-line, xcodebuild

How can i manipulate my iOS Target Properties by xcodebuild command tool ?

In example, i have one project with one target and with Facebook SDK Key in Target Properties in Info tab

```
FacebookAppID: 01234567891234
```

And with console command xcodebuild i'm compiling two Apps with Developer and Production provisions with two console commands:

For Developer:

```
xcodebuild -project Projectname.xcodeproj clean install OBJROOT=ObjRoot ... CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY={iPhoneDeveloper} PROVISIONING_PROFILE="Dev.mobileprovision"
```

For Distribution:

```
xcodebuild -project Projectname.xcodeproj clean install OBJROOT=ObjRoot ... CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY={iPhoneProduction} PROVISIONING_PROFILE="Prod.mobileprovision"
```

And i need use in Developer one FacebookAppID, and in Production a other FacebookAppID, and how i can change my command lines for realize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to xcodebuild are best used for values that change every time they're invoked, like a destination directory that includes a build number.

For data as foundational as a Facebook app ID, I'd recommend using your build configurations, e.g. "Debug" and "Release". Create a user-defined build setting (in Xcode 5.0.2, Editor -> Add Build Setting -> Add User-Defined Setting) named something like "FACEBOOK_ID", and in your Info.plist, set your desired key's value to ${FACEBOOK_ID}. In your target's build settings, define FACEBOOK_ID differently for your Debug and Release configurations. Your code then now has to pull the current value out of Info.plist at runtime.

If you really want to override build settings as arguments to xcodebuild, you can do so, just by adding "FACEBOOK_ID=12341234" to the end of the command, but this only works if you've done the work I just described to make FACEBOOK_ID into a configuration-specific build setting. I can't think of any sound reasons to keep this kind of app data outside of a build configuration.

If build configurations are new to you, I'd suggest starting with [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) session 408, "Working with Schemes and Projects in Xcode".

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i already solved this one by using two different build configurations files and in command i'm selecting a needing one. But idea with Debug/Release is too is success. And for this i give you a Accept aswer for my question =)